# Concept of measurement of entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

What is the concept of measurement of entanglement. In my mind, a state is either entangled or not. So how come a measurement is defined for it. Apparently, this function is called "concurrence" which ranges from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I understand your question correctly: Yes, it is true that the state of e.g. two photons can either be entangled or not. However, how do we experimentally measure such a state?

In the case of photons, we could let the potentially entangled photons travel along different directions and then add polarization filters after some distance. If the entangled state says that e.g. one photon is always vertically polarized while the other is always horizontally polarized we could rotate the filters 90° with respect to one another and should always detect the entangled pairs at the same time (assuming they travelled the same optical distance).

As the detectors will also pick up other photons and we might not be able to perfectly entangle each photon pair we generate (and as the filters might not be in perfect 90° position with one another, the filters might not be perfect and so on and so forth...) theres quite some room for errors. Thus, what you stumbled across might be talking about how well the state could be prepared, separated from the background noise and detected.